# Specify custom middleware execution order in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a custom middleware that identifies a tenant in the application. When I call the endpoint without 'auth' middleware it identifies the tenant correctly and can read the tables as required. However I need auth to execute after the tenant has been identified (i.e so the correct db is queried for the auth user) I can't seem to see where I have gone wrong with my configuration. I get an error that says:

> Undefined index: database

but this is because my identifyTenant middleware has not run to set the database at the point auth middleware tries to authenticate.

Route group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['tenant', 'auth', 'manager_admin']], function () {

Route::resource('invoice',  'InvoiceController');});
```

Priority middleware section of kernel.php as suggested here in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#sorting-middleware)

```
 protected $middlewarePriority = [
    // --- Added identify m.ware at the top to run first.
    \App\Http\Middleware\IdentifyTenant::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

Route middleware section of kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'tenant'         => \App\Http\Middleware\IdentifyTenant::class,
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

I am using laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

you cann try this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['tenant']], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['manager_admin']], function () {
            Route::resource('invoice',  'InvoiceController');
        });
    });
});
```

or

```
Route::resource('invoice',  'InvoiceController')->middleware('tenant')->middleware('auth')->middleware('manager_admin');
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working too. Auth still fires before tenant. Are the docs wrong or have I missed the point with  $middlewarePriority?

Comment: Same problem here. Tried many things without success. Did you find a solution?